# How to use Saxon with Wildfly properly?

Tags: xslt, wildfly, saxon

I have an issue with Saxon and WildFly 10.0.0.Final. I wrote some XSLTs and they work properly when I'm running unit tests but I get the issue when I run the same code on Wildfly.

In my pom.xml I have dependency like this:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
    <version>9.8.0-4</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried few version of Saxon and even I exchanged it for Xalan but still I'm getting the same issue. It works in unit testing but never with Wildfly. The problem is that "Wildfly case" simply ignore some parts of XSLT. For example this part is ignored:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$var33_Tracking/ns0:PartyIdentification/ns0:Location">
   <xsl:variable name="var13_LatLong" as="node()" select="ns0:LatLong"/>
   <xsl:variable name="var12_cur_as_string" as="xs:string" select="fn:string($var13_LatLong)"/>
   <xsl:variable name="var14_result" as="xs:string?">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="(fn:string(fn:string-length($var12_cur_as_string)) &gt; '0')">
            <xsl:sequence select="$var12_cur_as_string"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:GeoLoc">
               <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:for-each select="$var14_result">
      <LatitudinalHemisphere>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(fn:substring-before(., ',') &lt; '0')">
               <xsl:sequence select="'S'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:sequence select="'N'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </LatitudinalHemisphere>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It looks like some functions:
`fn:string-length` or `fn:substring-before` can cause this problem but I cannot figure out how to solve that issue. Any ideas or tips?

Comment: I would be surprised if anyone here could even begin to answer without some information about how you're trying to use the affected XSLT in Wildfly.  Generally speaking, "some information" should be a [mcve].  I acknowledge that that might be difficult for something deployed in an application server, but surely you can provide both more context and less cruft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of Wildfly, let alone having any expertise in it, so the best I can do is offer some diagnostic suggestions (apologies to SO purists who would argue that this is not an "answer", but it's too long for a comment.)

First, find out if trivial stylesheets run correctly and if they are actually running under Saxon. A simple way to do that is with a stylesheet along the lines of

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <p>Transformed using <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

If that works you can look at further system properties to determine the Saxon version (my suggestion above deliberately avoids using any system properties added in XSLT 2.0).

Are you able to see `xsl:message` output? You have a choice with diagnostics: you can either show them using `xsl:message`, or you can include them (temporarily of course) in the result document. Which approach you adopt depends on quite how broken your run-time environment is.

If simple things are working but the code you've shown us is "ignoring" the xsl:for-each instruction shown, then the first and most obvious possibility is that the select expression evaluates to an empty sequence. It's even possible that the compiler has removed the expression because it has decided the expression will always evaluate to an empty sequence. I would start by displaying count() applied to the expression:

```
count($var33_Tracking/ns0:PartyIdentification/ns0:Location)
```

Another thing to look at is whether the system is actually giving you diagnostics and you aren't seeing them. They might be going to a log file somewhere, for example.

You say you suspect that the use of functions like fn:string() has something to do with it. Can you pursue this suspicion and work out whether it is justified? The only unusual thing here is your use of the "fn" prefix, which is never necessary in XSLT. I can't see why that would cause failures in some environments and not others, but do check that the "fn" prefix is correctly declared, and see what happens if you change the function calls to be unprefixed.

It's worth being aware of the things that can make a transformation give different results in a different environment, and eliminating these as possible causes:

- Different source document or stylesheet parameters supplied
- Nodes have a different base URI
- Different XSLT software version or configuration
- Different XML parser (try to avoid the JDK parser, which is buggy: use Apache Xerces in preference)
- Unintended dependency on things that are intrinsically implementation-dependant, e.g. document-order of nodes in different XML trees, order of attributes
- Unintended dependency on current timezone or default language

You may feel you've already eliminated such causes, but I have to ask the question because you haven't given me any evidence that allows me to eliminate them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I will check this out soon and let you know how it helped.